# Is it possible to call your own endpoint using Giraffe, from that same web app?

Tags: f#, f#-giraffe

I have an F# WebAPI running in .net core 2.2. This application uses Giraffe.

Routing is setup in the way described [here](https://github.com/giraffe-fsharp/Giraffe/blob/c9e135d7c26d6418ac3eb7e1f2ab5b949ad08a7d/samples/SampleApp/SampleApp/Program.fs#L134).
An example:

```
let webApp =
choose [
    GET >=>
        choose [
            route  "/"           >=> text "index"
            route  "/ping"       >=> text "pong"
            route  "/error"      >=> (fun _ _ -> failwith "Something went wrong!")
            route  "/login"      >=> loginHandler
            route  "/logout"     >=> signOut authScheme >=> text "Successfully logged out."
            route  "/user"       >=> mustBeUser >=> userHandler
        ]
    route "/car"  >=> bindModel<Car> None json
    route "/car2" >=> tryBindQuery<Car> parsingErrorHandler None (validateModel xml)
    RequestErrors.notFound (text "Not Found") ]
```

We have a healthcheck that we'd like to run from within the application, and run against these routes - however we do not want to make external calls to our API (e.g. using a HttpClient or similar).

Is it possible to call these routes internally - without simply calling the functions they are routed to? We'd ideally like to be secure that our routing is working properly for all endpoints too.

Of course - we have tried the HttpClientFactory -> HttpClient fetch from external, but it results in issues with API Keys, external routing, multiple-environments, etc.

Any ideas would be welcomed!

Comment: What types issues would such a health check detect? Calling a health check endpoint from outside makes sense for detecting if the system is inoperational, but from inside?

Comment: From Inside - checking depencies such as Azure Blob Storage, Service Bus Queues - other APIs that we rely upon, and of course - as i said, "smoke test"-like functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Giraffe docs](https://github.com/giraffe-fsharp/Giraffe/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION.md#httphandler) webApp that you defined is HttpHandler. From docs:

```ml
type HttpFuncResult = Task<HttpContext option>
type HttpFunc = HttpContext -> HttpFuncResult
type HttpHandler = HttpFunc -> HttpContext -> HttpFuncResult
```

choose is a combinator which takes a list of HttpHandler and forms another HttpHandler.

As you see, HttpHandler is a function. So you can mock HttpContext and try to call webApp with HttpFunc parameter fun _ -> None. Something like:

```ml
let httpResult = webApp (fun _ -> None) mockedContext
```